# Spring Data Rest Warn when post an entity

Tags: java, spring-data-rest

I have a Spring Boot 2.5.2 project with Spring Data Rest (Lombok also).
Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(name = "IDX_COUNTRY_NAME_UNQ", columnNames = {"NAME"}),
        @UniqueConstraint(name = "IDX_COUNTRY_CODE_UNQ", columnNames = {"CODE"})
})
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class Country extends BaseNamedCodedEntity {
}
```

SuperClasses:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class BaseNamedCodedEntity extends BaseNamedEntity {
    @NotNull
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false, unique = true)
    protected String code;
}

@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class BaseNamedEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
}

@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;
}
```

All rest requests work fine. But when I send a simple POST with Postman:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "code": "Test"
}
```

entity saves in db, but in IDEA console I have a warn:

```
2021-06-26 19:24:33.097  WARN 15420 --- [nio-8090-exec-5] tion$ResourceSupportHttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource]]: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

When debugging by NullPointerException I catch it in `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.AggregateReferenceResolvingModule`
at method

```
public BeanDeserializerBuilder updateBuilder(DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, BeanDeserializerBuilder builder)
```

There I see in [property '_links'], propertyType: null.
Is that Spring Data Rest bug?

Comment: I ran across this as well when upgrading from Spring Boot 2.4.5 to 2.5.2 (upgrading Spring Data 3.4.8 to 3.5.1).  I'll update this when I get this issue tracked down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading Spring Boot to 2.5.3 will fix the issue.

This is was due to a bug that was introduced in Spring Data REST version 3.5.0 ([#2033](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/issues/2033)).  It has been fixed in Spring Data REST version 3.5.3, which is included in Spring Boot 2.5.3.